# Traffic meter [Xubuntu 15.04]

Tags: software-recommendation, traffic

is there any utility or application that can measure my traffic? I googled it and searching in Ubuntu software center, but i didn't find any.

Comment: When you say 'traffic meter' what exactly do you mean? Do you mean just something that will draw a chart? Or something which will show you the actual connections as they are happening? Or a way to view individual packets?

Comment: I meant just something that can show me how much data i transfered (downloaded/uploaded) in specific time interval, e.g. hour, day...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `vnstat` by running this in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install vnstat
```

Once installed, run `vnstat` in a terminal to show your internet usage.

Example output:

```
                  rx      /      tx      /     total    /   estimated
eth0:
   Jun '13     14.40 GiB  /    1.70 GiB  /   16.10 GiB
   Jul '13      3.57 GiB  /    2.55 GiB  /    6.12 GiB  /   40.44 GiB
 yesterday    968.58 MiB  /    2.26 GiB  /    3.21 GiB
     today    377.88 MiB  /   26.73 MiB  /  404.61 MiB  /     582 MiB
```

Source: https://superuser.com/questions/615958/how-to-track-internet-usage-upload-download-on-linux